# Loading Images in Android Expandable List View

Tags: android

Currently I have implemented Expandable List View referencing from the following website:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Now, how do I download a jpeg from a url(e.e. h--p://www.test.com/image.jpg) and display this image within each list child when that list child is chosen? Currently it only shows data.

The reason is being, I don't want to download the images and store within the assets folder which will increase the size of the application, that's why use url to show only when that list child is chosen.

Is it possible? Or I could only do so by downloading the image beforehand and storing under assets?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. If you want to implement this then you should grab a **lazy loading** library. For that you may use `aquery` just google it, its a nice library to provide the required mechanism.

Also Expandable `istview` is nothing but a `listview` so whatever you want to do inside a `listview`can be done within `ExpandableListView` as well.