# Setting height and width for a drawable

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In my application I use groupIndicator for an Expandable List View but images are not show correctly and have elongation, how can I set width and height for images?

This is my code:

```
<ExpandableListView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"/>
```

group_indicator.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/plus" android:state_empty="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/minus" android:state_expanded="true"/>    
</selector>
```

How can I fix it?

**EDIT:**

size of images : 32x32 pixel

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289637/loading-images-in-android-expandable-list-view And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534885/android-expandable-list and this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/ and this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: @RossC : those links can't help me, my problem is : image that i use for expandable list view has elongation and i don't know how can i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Android Jellybean have min-width,height for increase tap-able area.

if you image size for mdpi is 10x10

then you have to create a image 64x48 for 1x and center the image(10x10) and remaining area should be transparent.

OR

You just fixed the min-width,height to 10,10 respectively(width,height of your plus/minus image)